# Axios is fetching, but JSON is not displaying or being mapped

Tags: reactjs, json

in my code i'm trying to fetch a JSON file from an URL. The URL is being fetched (I checked Network), but it's still not displayed on the website. However, the JSON data appears in the console. I think the problem is that the JSON file isn't being mapped properly.

```
const Blog = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
      const getPosts = async () => {
            const response = await axios.get(`MYURL`)
            setPosts(response.data.posts)
            console.log(response)
        }

        getPosts()
    }, [])
    return (
      <div>
          {posts.map(article => {
              return(
                  <Blog 
                      title={article.title}
                      description={article.description}
                      url={article.url}
                      urltoimage={article.urltoimage} 
                  />
              )
          })}
      </div>
  )
}
```

I get the following errors when I try to run the application.

- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
- Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
- Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.

When I add a question mark before the mapping, like this:

```
{posts?.map(article =>
```

the errors don't come up anymore, but it still doesn't solve my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: The error is telling you that `posts` is `undefined`.  What do you expect `posts` to be *and why*?  What exact value does `response` contain?

Comment: Include an example of `console.log(response)` in your question.

Comment: I have a JSON file that has an object that contains arrays. I expect posts to be the JSON object i'm trying to map. Response contains the JSON URL I'm fetching.

Comment: @user20248756: Well, the error pretty clearly states that `posts` is `undefined`.  Which means, according to the code shown, `response.data.posts` is `undefined`.  Unless you have any indication otherwise, that's pretty much your answer.  You can use optional chaining (as you already do in the question) to prevent the error from halting execution of the problem.  Aside from that, your next step is to investigate why you expect `response.data.posts` to *not* be `undefined`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.